# Android Build Fail: D8: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-d8

We are splitting our app into 32 and 64 bit versions as per Google's requirements. As part of this change, we started using the D8 compiler instead of the older DEX compiler. When we use the D8 compiler, our build time has increased from 6 to 20 minutes (we have a large app). We have done extensive research online and the only solution to that we have found to reduce build time is to disable desugaring. However, the app will not build if the desugaring is disabled.

Updating the gradle version to 5.6 from 5.5.1 has not solved our issues when we turn desugaring off. Neither has removing the .gradle and build directories and invalidating + restarting the app. We are using
Android Studio version 3.5.

**Build error with android.enableD8.desugaring=false**

```
> Task :app:compileRegionNaDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator not present
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:85)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:54)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:41)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(MethodType.java:1067)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:406)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.gradle.internal.reflect.Instantiator not found
        at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.HeaderClassLoader.findClass(HeaderClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:83)
        ... 12 more
```

**gradle.properties file**

```
XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=false
android.databinding.enableV2=true
android.enableD8.desugaring=false
```

**build.gradle snippet**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.appmps.mobileapp.EspressoTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testApplicationId "com.appmps.mobileapp.test"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()

            if (isEmulatorRun()) {
                include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
            } else {
                include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"
            }

            universalApk false
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

We would be thankful for suggestions on getting our app to build with desugaring disabled. We are also interested in any additional strategies for reducing build time related to using the D8 compiler.

Thank you!